# Generic Method Type Safety

Tags: java, generics

I have the concept of `NodeType`s and `Node`s. A `NodeType` is a bunch of meta-data which you can create `Node` instances from (a lot like the whole Class / Object relationship).

I have various `NodeType` implementations and various Node implementations.

In my AbstractNodeType (top level for NodeTypes) I have ab abstract `createInstance()` method that will, once implemented by the subclass, creates the correct Node instance:

```
public abstract class AbstractNodeType {
  // ..

  public abstract <T extends AbstractNode> T createInstance();
}
```

In my `NodeType` implementations I implement the method like this:

```
public class ThingType {
  // ..

  public Thing createInstance() {
    return new Thing(/* .. */);
  }
}

// FYI
public class Thing extends AbstractNode { /* .. */ }
```

This is all well and good, but `public Thing createInstance()` creates a warning about type safety. Specifically:

> Type safety: The return type Thing for
>   createInstance() from the type
>   ThingType needs unchecked conversion
>   to conform to T from the type
>   AbstractNodeType

**What am I doing wrong to cause such a warning?**

**How can I re-factor my code to fix this?**

*`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is not good, I wish to fix this by coding it correctly, not ignoring the problem!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace `<T extends AbstractNode> T` with `AbstractNode` thanks to the magic of [covariant returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). `Java 5` added support, but it didn't receive the pub it deserved.

Comment: Holy crap that's cool. You're right, it really doesn't receive the pub it derserves!

Comment: Yeah, it's the only worthwhile thing I got out of that stupid SCJP book.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

(a) Don't use generics. It's probably not necessary in this case. (Although that depends on the code you havn't shown.)

(b) Generify AbstractNodeType as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractNodeType<T extends AbstractNode> {
  public abstract T createInstance();
}
public class ThingType<Thing> {
  public Thing createInstance() {
    return new Thing(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work:

```
interface Node{
}
interface NodeType<T extends Node>{
    T createInstance();
}
class Thing implements Node{}
class ThingType implements NodeType<Thing>{
    public Thing createInstance() {
        return new Thing();
    }
}
class UberThing extends Thing{}
class UberThingType extends ThingType{
    @Override
    public UberThing createInstance() {
        return new UberThing();
    }
}
```